# Radio Buttons in IE performing change functions, but not showing up as checked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am adding/removing classes based on whether or not something is checked, and it works fine in firefox, but IE will not show the value of the checkboxes. The change/click events fire, but the radio button doesn't actually show the selection, and this causes the validation to fail. Any idea what is happening?

Here is the code for the js function that changes the css:

```
function CheckHandlingUnit() {
    var flag = true;

    //Material Number
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatNum_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatNum_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatNum_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatNum_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatNum_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Description
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Des_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Des_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Des_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Des_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Des_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Material Type
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatType_DD").val() == "1") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatType_DD").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatType_DD").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatType_DD").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MatType_DD").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Inventory Classification
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Inv_DD").val() == "1") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Inv_DD").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Inv_DD").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Inv_DD").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Inv_DD").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Shelf Life
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB").val() == "" && !$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Unlimit_CB").is(":checked")) {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Charge Number
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Charge_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Charge_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Charge_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Charge_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Charge_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Quantity
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Quan_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Quan_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Quan_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Quan_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Quan_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Serialized Radio Button
    if (!($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Seri_RB_0").is(':checked')) &&
    !($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Seri_RB_1").is(':checked'))) {
        $("#seriVal").show();
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#seriVal").hide();
    }

    //Moisture Sensitive Radio Button
    if (!($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Moist_RB_0").is(':checked')) &&
    !($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Moist_RB_1").is(':checked'))) {
        $("#moistureVal").show();
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#moistureVal").hide();
    }

    //Hazardous Radio Button
    if (!($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Haz_RB_0").is(':checked')) &&
    !($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Haz_RB_1").is(':checked'))) {
        $("#hazardVal").show();
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#hazardVal").hide();
    }

    //Packaging Requirement
    if (!$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_0").is(':checked') &&
    !$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_1").is(':checked') &&
    !$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_2").is(':checked') &&
    !$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_3").is(':checked') &&
    !$("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_4").is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#packageVal").show();
        flag = false;
    }
    else{
        $("#packageVal").hide();
    }

    //package Other
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_PackingReq_CBL_2").is(':checked') && $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_OtherPkgRequirent_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_OtherPkgRequirent_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_OtherPkgRequirent_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_OtherPkgRequirent_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_OtherPkgRequirent_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }

    //Hazardous Material
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Haz_RB_0").is(':checked') && $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDS_TB").val() == "") {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDS_TB").addClass("TBDecoRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDS_TB").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDS_TB").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDS_TB").removeClass("TBDecoRed");
    }
    //File upload
    if ($("#ContentPlaceHolder2_Haz_RB_0").is(':checked') && $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDSFileUpload").val() == "") {
        flag = false;
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDSFileUpload").addClass("FileUploadRed");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDSFileUpload").removeClass("TBDecoNone");
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDSFileUpload").addClass("TBDecoNone");
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_MSDSFileUpload").removeClass("FileUploadRed");
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: returning false is probably what's happening, since you're stopping it from setting the value. Why do you return false?

Comment: you can rewrite all of the codes in 10 lines.

Comment: Well, it's a validation function that is checked in another function. If it returns true, then I can submit the form, if not, then don't submit/process the form. I was having problems before returning anything, too. It is only happening in IE, not firefox.

Comment: How exactly are you monitoring the check in javascript? Before this function gets called.

Comment: `function SaveMaterialData() {
    if (CheckHandlingUnit()) { ... do code.. }}`

Comment: Just so you know, you're making it really hard to follow. Can you show how you're generating the button in the page, where the event handler for the code monitors the radio button, and everything else. Preferably create a working demo that breaks in IE, but works in Firefox, using http://jsfiddle.net and share it with us.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. It did have to do with returning false, but in another part of the code. Thanks for your help. Add it as an answer, and I'll accept it.